# Prevent conversion to literal in terminal auto-completion

Tags: bash, terminal, centos

I recently changed from an older version to *CentOS 7.0.1406*. In terminal I am used to the auto completion, e.g. type `$> cd $DIR/tools/` and pressing the tab key to get a list of possible sub-dirs and dive further into.

On the new distro I am getting an automatical escape of the `$` when I press tab and therefore the variable can't be interpreted anymore. Why is this and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: GNU bash, Version 4.2.45(1)-release

Comment: Try `shopt -s direxpand`.

Comment: @whjm Thx this works! Now I was also able to find a description of the issue: https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/bash-4-2-variable-expansion-bug/